# Need help with Database Terminology

Tags: sql, terminology

If you have data in one table that should be in another table, what is their relationship called?

Comment: Why should it be in another table?

Answer (score 9):

The relationship is called **Healthy, yet dysfunctional**.

If you want to know the 'term' for it:

**De-Normalized**.

I say it's 'healthy' because *there are times* that developers want performance over sanity.  But just like any relationship, try not to make it the norm.

Edit: Yes, I stuck a double entendre about relationships in there.  It's Friday, I'm feeling frisky.

Answer (score 5):

I think the OP may have worded his question ambiguously and is really trying to ask, "What do you call the relationship in which an entry in one table references a row in another table?"  That is a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Unnormalized Junk?

Unnormalized  is a database that has never been normalized

Denormalized is a database that has been normalized at one time but someone has decided to shuffle some data around for a reason (could be performance)